# Booting in blind mode - after win10 update

Tags: dual-boot, 17.10, boot-repair

After updating Windows 10 and trying to boot Ubuntu 17.10, I have this error on my screen (dual boot Win10 and Ubuntu 17.10):

```
error: invalid video mode specification 'text'.  Booting in blind mode
```

I have tried `boot-repair` with Ubuntu 17.10 LiveCD but the problem is still there. My laptop is HP Elitebook 840 G3.

according to  David Foerster comment:
boot-info report is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MWSQ9jGDnb/

Comment: Could you please run [Boot-Info](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log? Thanks.

Comment: boot-info report: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MWSQ9jGDnb/

Comment: Did you follow the advice in the section "Final advice in case of suggested repair" all the way at the bottom?

Comment: first line said: Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sdb2/efi/.../grub*.efi file! but how i can do that!? in laptop bios setup i cant find any option that can choose boot on grub*.efi file

Comment: Please consult the manual for your computer’s BIOS for the exact steps. Other than that the subsequent advices provide alternatives.

Comment: i can do first line of Final advice in HP Bios, but that can't help me. do you have any advice? can i reinstall Ubuntu with keep my data

Comment: A re-installation would not solve the underlying issue with the UEFI configuration (as far as I understand it) since it persists across operating systems. Did you try the other steps under "Final advice in case of suggested repair", i. e. change the boot order either in the BIOS settings or via `bcdedit` in Windows?